# How do i add two additional checkout fields in the checkout page? (date and time fields)

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, additional-information

I want to add two additional fields to the checkout page. A delivery-date fields (that can only have the date of at least tomorrow) and a delivery-time field (which can only be between two set times).

I've been trying to do this on my own, but i'm pretty new to Magento (not code in general, just Magento).

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated :)